# Developing an app on glass that runs recursively

Tags: android, google-glass

I have created an app on Glass that has a input prompt in addition to the voice trigger. The app has two activities, say A and B. A gets some input through voice prompt and passes it on to B which processes the input and produces the output. Now, what I need is a way to make the app get the voice prompt recursively which would lead to execution of the app from Activity A, until the user wants to exit the app. Something similar to a do..while() .

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that does the processing, Activity A can pass requests to the Service. The Service should stop when processing complete and can start up again when the next voice trigger occurs (which might be soon, might be in a long time, might never happen) - so make sure the Service isn't hogging memory/cpu resources when it's not actually needed. If you must have 2 Activities, the Service can create B (in which case you may want to bind the Service to B so it stops when B finishes).